# Xcode Jenkins Build Failure The following build commands failed: CompileSwift normal arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am trying to setup a continuous integration for an Ios App using Jenkins. I used xcode shell command for build process:

> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "PhoenixiOS.xcworkspace" -scheme
>   "PhoenixiOSTest" -configuration Release archive

Build triggered and finally  the following error  displayed 
 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
 The following build commands failed:

> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>     CompileSwift normal arm64

The Git code is working other Developers Laptop and The code is working on other work spaces like Desktop with the shell command. Only in  Jenkins JOB work space it is producing this Error.

**log last lines --code**

> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixiOS-calcgxkedqnxdqcshfjebjolxcut/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixiOSTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PhoenixiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/PhoenixiOSTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/EnableLocationServicesView.d
>   -num-threads 4 -output-filelist /var/folders/jc/fl1lw1754rvd8568qp_wcf5w00008b/T/outputs-f754ba
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Phoenix_IOS_D/PhoenixiOS/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header.h:7:9:
>   error: 'NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h' file not found

`#import "NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h"`

1 error generated.

> :0: error: failed to emit precompiled header
>   '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixiOS-calcgxkedqnxdqcshfjebjolxcut/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixiOSTest/PrecompiledHeaders/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header-swift_344FHIEQ5169K-clang_9521NPKFGEEZ.pch'
>   for bridging header
>   '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Phoenix_IOS_D/PhoenixiOS/PhoenixiOS-Bridging-Header.h'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>     CompileSwift normal arm64 (2 failures) Build step 'Execute shell'
>   marked build as failure

Comment: I have the Answer.  it was due to code Pipeline unable to unzip .git files. better to clone using git ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to code Pipeline unable to unzip .git files. better to clone using git ssh.